# Weird python literal indexing : ['False', 'True'][condition]

Tags: python

This is what I understood:

```
>>> ['False', 'True'][True]
'True'
>>> ['False', 'True'][False]
'False'
>>>
```

And now i tried the following snippet and got TypeError:

```
>>> c = 'a'
>>> ['Invalid', ['x']*c][type(c) is int]
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>
```

So, when i change the ['x']*c into False, then it works:

```
>>> ['Invalid', 'False'][type(c) is int]
'Invalid'
>>>
```

And: i change c to 2:

```
>>> c = 2
>>> ['Invalid', ['x']*c][type(c) is int]
['x', 'x']
>>>
```

NB: :I know if - else can do it, but thats not my point here.

Comment: And what is your point here; you never say.  What don't you understand about your example?

Comment: Did you understand it correctly? `['False', 'True'][True]` yields `'True'` because `True` indexes the list with `1`.

Comment: i know that but it checks all the expression on the left side are executed before checking the condition on the right side. My point here was the error :) sorry if i make you confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ternary operator: no short-circuit evaluation.

In the expression `['Invalid', ['x']*c][type(c) is int]`, `['Invalid', ['x']*c]` is evaluated first regardless of the following indexing   to populate list object items.

You'd better use conditional expression:

```
['x'] * c if isinstance(c, int) else 'Invalid'
```

Comment: I am not asking about how to rewrite it, i was trying to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @yopy, I provided the reason, didn't I?

Comment: I know that conditional expression, i was trying to understand why that error out.

Comment: List literal `['Invalid', ['x']*c]` is executed regardless of `[type(c) is int]`.

Comment: hm that make sense, but how can i prove that.

Comment: @yopy, Replace that with some kind of functino call. `[something(), other_thing()][False]`. (Make `something`, `other_thing` to print something to prove it)

Comment: You are right, it calls everytime,

Comment: >>> def foo():
...     print 'foo'
...
>>> ['Invalid', foo()][type(c) is int]
foo
'Invalid'
>>>

Comment: @yopy, My point was: It's not a ternary oeprator: no shortcircuit evaluation.

Comment: so, what we called this kind of operation ?

Comment: @yopy you could also prove it by noticing that the error you get from `['Invalid', ['x']*c][type(c) is int]` is the same as the error you get from just `['x']*c` - "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'".

Comment: @yopy, It's just a list literal with indexing. I don't know specific naming for this kind of trick.

Comment: @Ivc, actually what you are saying is right, but I was not thinking that way.

Comment: It's just a list literal followed by a subscript.  As in y=['Invalid', ['x', 'x']]; y[0]; y[True]

Answer (score 4):

```
['Invalid', ['x']*c]
```

This entire list has to be generated, even if you are getting only `0`th element. While constructing the list, if `c` is a string, Python fails to evaluate `['x']*c`. That's why it fails.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this isn't a real ternary operator; it's a list, and the entire list will be evaluated before it looks at the subscript.

Chances are, what you actually want is:

```
['x']*c if type(c) == int else 'Invalid'
```

The reason the list hack "works" in some cases is that `True` and `False` cast to `1` and `0`. But what you're doing is building the list (including both the true and false paths) then using the subscript to choose an element in the list.

Maybe it's clearer why the original idea fails if we remove the subscript and just write the list:

```
c = 'a'
choices = ['Invalid', ['x']*c]
```

It's obvious why `choices` throws a `TypeError`, right? So you can't subscript it because it never finishes evaluating.

Comment: Example for the last part http://paste.ubuntu.com/6853399/

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that the point of constructing a valid list before trying to conditionally operate on it is being understood by the poster of the question.  ['X']*c, when c is a character, will fail.

Comment: you can forget for constructing a list, it could be anything you want, But, what i was trying to figure out was why it called if the condition is false, and I found out that before it checks the condition it check for all the expression on the left side.

Comment: Yeah. That was what the other persons comment about short circuiting was about. Glad you figured it out!